# User Research: Google Forms for Screener then Send Calendly Invite once crieteria is met

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

Using Google Forms to present a screener. Based on user responses that meet certain criteria will then prompt to send user a calendly invite to schedule a one-on-one interview.

I've tried adjusting the column position for email. Any suggestions?

I test the form and is activated by onFormSubmit by new form submission and the log gives me this:

> Head  onFormSubmit    Trigger Sep 22, 2023, 3:01:30 PM    0.754 s
> Completed
> Cloud logs
> Sep 22, 2023, 3:01:31 PM    Info    Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

My google sheet goes like:

[Goog sheets of Google Form Screener responses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdofD.png)

My script goes like:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  try {
    // Get the form responses
    var form = FormApp.openById('MY_FORM_ID');
    var responses = e.values;
    
    // Define criteria
    var ageCriteria = ['25-35', '36-45'];
    var familyCriteria = ['Single with Kids.', 'Married/Cohabiting with 1-2 kids.', 'Married/Cohabiting with 3 or more kids.'];
    var interestCriteria = 'Yes';
    
    // Retrieve the recipient's email address from the second column
    var recipient = responses[0]; // Assuming the email question is the second question
    
    // Check if criteria are met
    var ageResponse = responses[1]; // Assuming the age question is in the third column
    var familyResponse = responses[2]; // Assuming the family is in fourth column
    var interestResponse = responses[6]; // Assuming interest is in the seventh column
    
    if (ageCriteria.includes(ageResponse) && familyCriteria.includes(familyResponse) && interestResponse === interestCriteria) {
      // Criteria are met, send Calendly invitation
      sendCalendlyInvitation(recipient);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any errors
    Logger.log("Error: " + error.toString());
  }
}

// Function to send Calendly invitation
function sendCalendlyInvitation(recipient) {
  try {
    // Replace with your Calendly link
    var calendlyLink = 'https://calendly.com/pdskains/fake-calendly-interview-link';
    
    // Create a new email with Calendly link
    var subject = 'Interview Invitation';
    var body = 'Thank you for your interest in our research. Please schedule an interview using the following link: ' + calendlyLink;
    
    // Send the email to the retrieved recipient's email address
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any errors
    Logger.log("Error: " + error.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe responses[0] is actually a timestamp

Comment: so i have tried it with 1 and i get the same error, ive also tried 2 and same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot know the error line of your script. But, from your error message of `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`, if your error occurred at `var recipient = responses[0];`, I guess that it indicates that the value of `e` has no property of `values`. If my understanding is correct, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? By the way, which is your script the containe-bound script of Google Spreadsheet or Google Form?

Comment: Perhaps you are using the wrong onFormSubmit trigger.  There's one for a spreadsheet and one for the form

Comment: The question doesn't include enough details. It doesn't mention if the project is contained and in such case by which application is contained, or if it's a stand-alone project. It doesn't mention either how the trigger was created either.

Comment: The script is written in app script. You go to Google forms and click on script editor. The trigger is created in app script. It is set on the onFormSubmit function. The script is being triggered the error is saying it can't grab the email for whatever reason. I don't know what people are referring to stand alone or contained. This is all within the Google forms and app script by Google.

Answer (score 0):

`You go to Google forms and click on script editor. The trigger is created in app script. It is set on the onFormSubmit function.`

The problem with the script is that it should be linked to a spreadsheet NOT the Google Form.

There are two types of `onFormSubmit` trigger

- **Google Form** - executes when a user modifies the form
- **Google Sheets** - executes when a user submits a response to a Google Form.

In this case, the script is "linked" (the correct term is [bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound)) to the Google Form.  So the trigger will not run when/as expected. The solution is to create a new spreadsheet (or identify an existing spreadsheet) that can be used to accept response details from the Google Form.

**Form**

- link the Form to the spreadsheet (under the "Responses" tab)

**Sheets**

- open the spreadsheet, open the Apps Script project editor,
- paste the script below, save the script
- manually install the `onFormSubmit` trigger for the script

**Script changes**

The script shown below is almost identical to the OP script. The differences are:

- deleted:  `var form = FormApp.openById('MY_FORM_ID');` - not necessary
- updated index reference for variables. Since the timestamp is in Column A (index=0), the index for variables will be the "column number minus one"

  - `var recipient = responses[1]`
  - `var ageResponse = responses[2]`
  - `var familyResponse = responses[3]`
  - `var interestResponse = responses[6]`

---

```
function formResponse(e) {
  try {
    // Get the form responses
    var responses = e.values
    
    // Define criteria
    var ageCriteria = ['25-35', '36-45'];
    var familyCriteria = ['Single with Kids.', 'Married/Cohabiting with 1-2 kids.', 'Married/Cohabiting with 3 or more kids.'];
    var interestCriteria = 'Yes';
    
    // Retrieve the recipient's email address from the second column
    // Timestamp will be index 0, so +1 for index reference for each question
    var recipient = responses[1]; // Assuming the email question is the second question
    
    // Check if criteria are met
    var ageResponse = responses[2]; // Assuming the age question is in the third column
    var familyResponse = responses[3]; // Assuming the family is in fourth column
    var interestResponse = responses[6]; // Assuming interest is in the seventh column
    
    if (ageCriteria.includes(ageResponse) && familyCriteria.includes(familyResponse) && interestResponse === interestCriteria) {
      // Criteria are met, send Calendly invitation
      sendCalendlyInvitation(recipient);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle any errors
    Logger.log("Error: " + error.toString());
  }
}
```